# Join two tables and only output rows that exist in the first table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm working on a form that allows users to apply for several award categories. They can apply for all several categories, but can only apply for each category once.

The award categories are stored in this table:
[image]

When a user applies for a category, a row is entered into the following table with the user's nominee_id and award_category_id:
[image]

I then is this code to show the user which awards they have applied already, which works fine.

```
$result = mysql_query("                         
                        SELECT 
                            award_subsection.*,
                            award_subsection.title AS subsection_title,
                            award_nomination_category.*
                        FROM 
                            award_subsection INNER JOIN
                            award_nomination_category
                        ON
                            award_subsection.id=award_nomination_category.award_category_id
                        WHERE
                            award_subsection.active='1' AND
                            award_subsection.award_id='$id' AND
                            award_subsection.additional_function='award category' AND
                            award_nomination_category.active='1' AND
                            award_nomination_category.award_id='$id' AND
                            award_nomination_category.nominee_id='$nominee_id'
                    ");
                    $category_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    if($category_count > 0) {
                        echo'
                        <div id="column_full" class="reverse_margin">
                            <div id="subsection_heading">
                                <h3>You have already selected the following award categories:</h3>
                            </div><!--
                            --><div id="subsection_content">
                                <!--
                        ';
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo '
                                    --><div id="column_third">
                                        <h3>' . $row['subsection_title'] . '</h3>
                                    </div><!--
                            ';
                        }
                        echo'
                                    -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ';
                    }
```

But my problem is when I also want to render a drop down menu that only shows the categories the user have not applied to. The following code works with the user has only applied for 1 category previously, but when the user applies for more than 1, the drop down menu displays all categories. I suspect this is because since there are 2 rows of application from the same user, the script is running through the table twice and getting all of the categories.

```
 $result = mysql_query("                            
SELECT 
    award_subsection.*,
    award_subsection.id AS subsection_id,
    award_subsection.title AS subsection_title,
    award_nomination_category.*
FROM 
    award_subsection JOIN
    award_nomination_category
ON
    award_subsection.id!=award_nomination_category.award_category_id
WHERE
    award_subsection.active='1' AND
    award_subsection.award_id='$id' AND
    award_subsection.additional_function='award category' AND
    award_nomination_category.active='1' AND
    award_nomination_category.award_id='$id' AND
    award_nomination_category.nominee_id='$nominee_id'
GROUP BY
    award_subsection.id
 ");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '
    <option value="' . $row['subsection_id'] . '">' . $row['subsection_title'] . '</option>
';
 }
```

Is there a way for the php to know which categories were selected in the first query and remove them in the second query? Thx in advance!

Comment: instead of `JOIN` on whats not in the table you should do a LEFT OUTER JOIN which will join without filtering..

Comment: just tried LEFT OUTER JOIN, same result

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!

Here's the code if anyone's interested:

```
                        // Check for applied categories
                    $result = mysql_query("                         
                        SELECT 
                            award_subsection.*,
                            award_subsection.id AS subsection_id,
                            award_subsection.title AS subsection_title,
                            award_nomination_category.*
                        FROM 
                            award_subsection INNER JOIN
                            award_nomination_category
                        ON
                            award_subsection.id=award_nomination_category.award_category_id
                        WHERE
                            award_subsection.active='1' AND
                            award_subsection.award_id='$id' AND
                            award_subsection.additional_function='award category' AND
                            award_nomination_category.active='1' AND
                            award_nomination_category.award_id='$id' AND
                            award_nomination_category.nominee_id='$nominee_id'
                    ");
                    $category_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    if($category_count > 0) {
                        echo'
                        <div id="column_full" class="reverse_margin">
                            <div id="subsection_heading">
                                <h3>You have already selected the following award categories:</h3>
                            </div><!--
                            --><div id="subsection_content">
                                <!--
                        ';
                        // Create array of IDs that the nominee has already applied for
                        $selected_categories = array();
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $selected_categories[] = $row['subsection_id'];
                            echo '
                                    --><div id="column_third">
                                        <h3>' . $row['subsection_title'] . '</h3>
                                    </div><!--
                            ';
                        }
                        echo'
                                    -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ';
                    }
                    echo'
                        <form method="post" action="award-nomination-submit.php" data-parsley-validate>
                            <div id="column_full" class="reverse_margin">                           
                                <input type="hidden" name="award_id" value="' . $id . '">
                                <input type="hidden" name="nominee_id" value="' . $nominee_id . '">
                                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="' . $step . '">

                                <h3>Select an Award Category:</h3>
                                <select class="visual_form" name="award_category"  required>
                                    <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
                    ';
                    // Build award categories drop down
                    $result = mysql_query("                         
                        SELECT 
                            *
                        FROM 
                            award_subsection
                        WHERE
                            active='1' AND
                            award_id='$id' AND
                            additional_function='award category'
                    ");
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        // If ID exists in array, don't echo out in drop down
                        if(in_array($row['id'], $selected_categories)) {
                            echo'';
                        }
                        else {
                            echo '
                                <option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</option>
                            ';
                        }
                    }
                    echo '
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                    ';
```

Basically, I created an array out of the IDs that were output from the first sql query. Then in the second sql query, I compared ID with IDs in the array and only echo out the ones that doesn't match :)